# Communication b/w JavaScript Files via Post/Dispatch message in safari extension like in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, safari-extension, safari-web-inspector

We are going to develop Safari Extension. We have Chrome Extension.

And we want to merge the same code in safari extension, Is there any possibility to do so.

But as per chrome structure , Chrome using Background Js to communicate with Addon and internal JS. Via chrome.runtime.sendMessage.
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
Can we use something like that in safari Extension, A Background file that can handle all the messaging?

We can communicate via Post Messaging/Dispatch Message;

Add-on/Global   =>> Injected Script. =>> Add-on/Global File.

But We want to communicate between JavaScript files (loaded with Global/Popover Html File) via Post/Dispatch Messaging like in Chrome(chrome.runtime.sendMessage).

Local.JS  =>> BackGruound.Js =>> Local.JS
BackGruound.Js = > Content.Js =>> global.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has a guide on [Converting Chrome Extensions to Safari Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/ConvertingToSafari/ConvertingToSafari.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH25-SW1):

> If your Chrome extension used browser or page actions, use toolbar items in Safari. If you used popups in Chrome, use a popover in Safari. If you used a background page, use the global page in Safari. You can also modify some parts of your UI at runtime—for example, you can disable toolbar items and add contextual menu items.
>
> The events that occur in Safari are based on the DOM event system, described in Document Object Model Events and UIEvents. To set up an event listener, call the addEventListener method on the object that should listen for the event. Any instance of SafariEventTarget or its subclasses can register event listeners. For security reasons, you can dispatch messages only within your own extension.
>
> The Safari API is divided into two parts: the web content layer, which runs inside the web content area, and the application layer, which runs outside of it. To communicate between scripts running in different layers, use messages. In Safari, there is no difference between short-term message passing and long-term connections; you use the same methods for both.

To send messages between the global page and injected scripts, you would use Safari's [Messages and Proxies](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/MessagesandProxies/MessagesandProxies.html).